# Swift declare that AnyClass object implements protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I am currently writing a framework for creating plugins for my OS X application. These plugins are loaded as `NSBundle`s, and the bundles' `principalClass`es are used to run the plugin code. However, I can't figure out how to declare that the `principalClass` object conforms to my protocol.

```
let bundles = CFBundleCreateBundlesFromDirectory(kCFAllocatorDefault, NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundleDirectory), "bundle") as NSArray

for bundle in bundles
{
    let bundleClass = bundle.principalClass!!

    if (bundleClass.conformsToProtocol(MyProtocol.self))
    {
        //Produces compiler error:
        //"Cannot downcast from 'AnyClass' to non-@objc protocol type 'MyProtocol'"
        let loadedClass = bundleClass as MyProtocol
    }
}
```

What is the proper syntax for declaring that it conforms to this protocol?
(Also, this protocol is declared `@objc` so I'm not sure why it says "non-@objc" protocol.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try: `bundleClass as MyProtocol.Protocol`. The docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1137).

BTW, your code can be simplified

```
let bundles = CFBundleCreateBundlesFromDirectory(kCFAllocatorDefault, NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundleDirectory), "bundle") as NSArray
for bundle in bundles {
    if let loadedClass = bundle.principalClass as? MyProtocol.Protocol {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, we can use `MyProtocol.Type` in swift 4