# How to create an instance of a principal class from a loadable bundle in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create an instance of a principal class from a loadable bundle in swift. All I know about the class is that it conforms to a specific protocol (NOT @objc protocol) and it is NOT a subclass of NSObject. Is this possible at all?

It was so simple in Obj-C with NSObject, because really, obj-c doesn't care about types, but this swift, oh man, the principalClass property of NSBundle returns AnyClass?, how is it possible on Earth to create an instance of that AnyClass? type and tell it that now it conforms to a swift protocol?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321872/swift-declare-that-anyclass-object-implements-protocol ?

Comment: @MartinR, I've already tried that, it doesn't work. Maybe it used to work in previous versions, but not anymore :(

Comment: I have found a solution, it is ugly, but I will have to mark it is an answer if nobody has anything better. So, as I see my non-objc swift class which conforms to non-objc swift protocol cannot be passed through the principleClass mechanism. So I created objc principle class with a function returning bridged swift instance.

Answer (score 2):

Non-`@objc` protocols do not carry runtime type information: this means that you cannot use the `as` operator to convert from a class type to your protocol type if the relationship is not known at compile-time. `@objc` protocols, on the other hand, do carry runtime type information.

If your protocol was marked `@objc` and declared at least one initializer, you should be able to do this:

```
if let bundle = NSBundle(...) {
    if let meta = bundle.principalClass as? MyProtocol.Type {
        let obj: MyProtocol = meta(initParam: a, initParam2: b, ...)
    }
}
```

... except that the current Swift compiler will [crash](https://github.com/practicalswift/swift-compiler-crashes/blob/master/crashes/22524-collectfullname.swift) if you try to convert `AnyType` to a protocol type like that. It works if you can use a class type instead of a protocol type, though.

Comment: To initialize you actually need to do

`let obj: MyProtocol = meta.init(initParam: a, initParam2: b, ...)`